# Background processes periodically eat up my CPU time on OS X 10.10.4, Yosemite

Tags: macos, launchd, kernel-panic, cpu

Periodically the CPU on my iMac Mid-2015 running OS X 10.10.4, gets used almost exclusively by:

- `launchd`: ~70%
- `fseventsd`: 12%
- `UserEventAgent`: ~40%
- `opendirectoryd`: 20%
- `notifyd`: 12%

I have tried quitting programs (e.g. Chrome, Outlook etc.) and no apparent process seems to be the culprit.  It seems to occur once an hour (at least it has done it 3 times in the last 3 hours) and each episode lasts ~10-30minutes.  It does not appear to be reproducible with any action that I take.

If I open Console.app, in **system.log**, there are many repeated errors, such as:

```
Aug  6 16:29:11 DREWGEHRYW13 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.google.keystone.user.agent[60455]): Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.`
```

These errors are not generated the entire time when this behavior is occurring, but it seems that they are written every few minutes (even when Chrome is closed).

In **System Log Queries -> All Messages** : There aren't any recent messages

Also, possibly related, I have experienced 2 kernel panics in the past week caused by `launchd` (or processes launched by it), but I will limit this question to solely the CPU issue for now.

What is causing this and how do I fix this?

Comment: Logs do not lie => google. Though, assuming that your iMac is using 4  cores then there still should be plenty of processing power left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I checked Chrome and it states that

```
Version 43.0.2357.65(64-bit)
Update failed (error: 12)
```

It appears that my [version](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/07/stable-channel-update_21.html) is out of date by about 3 weeks.  So I believe that Chrome was periodically trying to frantically update and would subsequently fail.  I followed the recommendations of [Google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1367288?hl=en) and attempted removing the appropriate files, but my version of Chrome would still not update.

I ended up uninstalling Chrome by dragging the icon from Applications to the trash and removing ~/Library/Google and /Library/Google (not sure why it is here also...).  I reinstalled Chrome and it appears that I now have the most up to date version of Chrome (44.0.2403.103) and I have yet to experience any of those errors or cooking of my cpu.  I have been at my desktop now for 4 hours, so hopefully this issue has been resolved.  I'll also see if I experience anymore kernel panics, hopefully these issues were related and both are resolved.

Comment: This fixed the kernel panic problems.  It is now 3 months later and I have yet to have another one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but may be a partial solution.

I've been seeing high CPU and memory usage from `UserEventAgent`, and the only fix that I found after much searching was to disable `Notification Center`. It's quite possible that only part of `Notification Center` is the problem, or one particular app's notifications, but I haven't had the time to troubleshoot that yet.

To disable Notification Center, do these two commands in Terminal:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
killall NotificationCenter
```